# Rails server on Heroku not reachable from some locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

Our server (Rails 3.2 on Heroku) is in production for more than a year. It has an SSL Endpoint certificate on www. subdomain. All following requests are redirected to https://www.myproject.com:

- http:// myproject.com
- https:// myproject.com
- http:// www.myproject.com

Some customers get error message "Browser cannot find server". When they go to http:// myproject.com the redirect happens and browser shows https:// www.myproject.com url, but doesn't load anything. Such request doesn't reach the server according to the server logs. I asked the customer to run nslookup and it gives the following output, which is fine:

```
nslookup myproject.com
Server:   192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: myproject.com
Address: 64.27.57.29
Name: myproject.com
Address: 64.27.57.24
```

And the same request for www. subdomain from the customer's machine gives the following:

```
nslookup www.myproject.com
Server:   192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1#53

*** www.myproject.com not found. Not existing domain.
```

When I run the same command from my machine I get the following expectable output:

```
nslookup www.myproject.com
Server:   192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.myproject.com canonical name = shiga-9999.herokussl.com.
shiga-9999.herokussl.com  canonical name = elb004444-58533464.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name: elb004444-58533464.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 107.22.187.137
Name: elb004444-58533464.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.243.204.31
Name: elb004444-58533464.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 184.73.182.255
```

We have few customers who have reported the same problem, they live in different countries and they are connected to Internet through different providers and cannot access our server at all. I could never reproduce the issue myself.

Has anyone experienced similar issue? What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue? Similar issue and setup here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611057/amazon-route-53-heroku-app-not-accessible-from-certain-places-what-to-do

I switched off our ssl and moved cname from nagano to pure herokuapp for that reason, not yet sure if it helps. How did it go on your end?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by moving Heroku app to another region. I spent hours searching for root cause but didn't find it.