# Amazon Route 53 + Heroku app not accessible from certain places - what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I am working on a Heroku and don't have much background in networking.

The app I am working on seems to be unreachable from some places.

1. We got reports from people not being able to access it
2. A ping service we use (Statuscake) reports that the site is consistently unreachable from certain node locations

To fix that, we moved DNS to Amazon Route 53.

A week after, there is a change in what countries work by the ping service, but essentially we're still permanently down for some world locations, while maintaining almost 100% uptime in others.

Unfortunately, none of the people who reported site down are able to debug with us.

What are the things to do / check in such situation?